# How to rotate a zoomed MKMapView on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, autorotate

I am attempting to enable autorotation in my App, which includes an MKMapView.  I enable autorotation in my view controller by always returning yes in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.  This works fine if my map hasn't been zoomed.  However, if I set the region prior to rotating, I end up with a white bar at the side of the map when in landscape mode.

To demonstrate, I added the following code to viewDidLoad and then rotated to landscape mode after the app launches.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
double currentlat = 40.0;
double currentlon = -105.0;

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = currentlat;
NSLog(@"LL, %f, %f", currentlat, currentlon);
region.center.longitude = currentlon;
region.span.latitudeDelta = .0010;
region.span.longitudeDelta = .0010;
NSLog(@"Set Region Call");
MKCoordinateRegion fittedregion = [MainMapView regionThatFits:region];
[MainMapView setRegion:fittedregion animated:TRUE];
```

Comment: Are you sure you have autosizing of the width turned on for the map view control?

Comment: Yes, I checked that.  Also, if I remove the call to setRegion, the MKMapView resizes as expected.

Comment: I have worked around this by resizing the MKMapView in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation twice.  I first shrink the view and then reset it to the window size.  I don't like this solution and would like to know the proper way to solve the issue.